# what to do to efficiently develop web applications with jsf

Tags: jsf-1.2, icefaces-1.8

I am a newbie to web development. I need to develop an application using jsf and icefaces. What do I do to develop an efficient web application using these technologies. What are books, resources available for them especially for icefaces means where can I get code snippets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you really tied to JSF 1.2 and IceFaces 1.8? I only ask because I think the old IceFaces version won't get much love anymore. It has been there for over two years now. Almost all providers of component libraries (IceFaces, RichFaces, PrimeFaces) focus on JSF 2. But back to your Question:

- Key to success with JSF 1.2 -> [Facelets](http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html)
- Write your pages in XHTML (using Facelets) and not in JSP
- Tutorials:

  - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/java/libraryview.jsp?search_by=nonbelievers:
  - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-facelets/
- IceFaces code snippets:

  - http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface
- IceFaces IDE Support (unfortunately only for older IDE versions)

  - http://www.icefaces.org/main/downloads/os-downloads-1-8.iface

You will have to check the IceFaces [issue tracker](http://jira.icefaces.org/browse/ICE?report=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3aversions-panel) sometimes. And you should have a look at their [community forum](http://www.icefaces.org/JForum/forums/list.page) as well, when you get stuck.

Other than that, you need to provide more specific information on what you need sources for :) Good Luck!